# Google account (ie OpenID) on a pendrive

Tags: openid, usb-storage, google-accounts

Is it possible to store a Google Account/OpenID details on a USB drive so that instead of typing in the details you can just plug in the USB drive. Without any modification to the Browser. I use different computers a lot, and can't be bothered to keep typing in my details (can't have random computers having my details kept logged in).

Comment: wow good question! +1 this would be useful for all kinds of accounts, besides Google...however this would be somewhat insecure...

Comment: not necessarily, it could be made so that you have to link the usb drive to your account, that way if you lose you usb drive you can disable it. Also should you lose your usb drive and not realise until someone finds it and uses it to access your account, there is a password/passphrase that can only be set once and not changed which can be used to override the pen drive and give your account back.

Comment: I'm sure there are other ways that it can be made secure as well. Like not using the same username/password as you do to enter normally, or just storing hashes/encryptions of your username/password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like [Portable Firefox](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable) on the drive might work, but I think it's up to the app (ie, an app that only checks cookies might work, but an app that verifies by IP address also probably will not).

Comment: That wouldn't work because the app sets it's own cookie, it doesn't use one issued by the OpenID provider. You can't "save" the OpenID login.

Comment: However, the use of Portable Firefox would allow browser modification to the effect of automatically logging into any openid pages.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to (securely) keep your logins (incl. OpenIDs) safe on your drive is to use [Firefox Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable) coupled with [KeePass Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/keepass_portable).
(By that I mean use Firefox Portable but disable its password manager and use keepass for that purpose instead.)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know - this isn't possible.

The closest I can think of is that you could always use Apache or any webserver and install a OpenID service on it, then have that as an OpenID provider - you would then have to use something such as DynDNS to make sure that the DNS record is the same (mind you, I am not an OpenID expert, maybe this isn't required) - but you would still have to ensure that the firewall of wherever you are allows incoming connections to where you are running the web server.

... And, after re-reading, I think I got your entire question wrong - if you just want to take passwords with you, I would recommend [KeePass](http://keepass.info/)

Answer (score -1):

## Not possible

The OpenID provider merely authenticates, the application (web site) itself sets a cookie. You can't "save" the OpenID login.

Comment: No I just want to store my username and password, so it logs in when I have a pen drive inserted.

Comment: @Jonathan: Then use portable firefox.

Comment: Bad idea. Firefox has no encryption of passwords.